# How can I close window after refresh page?

Tags: javascript

How can I close window opened:

```
var open_win;
function open(){
    open_win = window.open("myfile.php", "name", "height=500, width=400");
}
```

now when I use:

```
function close(){
    open_win.close();
}
```

a window is closed. However when I refresh a page I cannot use **open_win.close()**.

How can I close window after refresh page?

Comment: You can't, you loose the reference to the window.

Comment: (and there is no way to store it between page reloads)

Comment: suddenly think of a scenario (untested). If `window.open('http://example.com','target window name');` is used to open a window with name "target window name", what will happen when the page is refreshed & run the same script again? not tested yet.

Comment: Tested in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE6-10 and works correctly. Thanks